# Upgrading to cedar-14 when deploying via the heroku API

Tags: heroku

To migrate from cedar to cedar-14 the docs says to first to a `heroku stack:set cedar-14` and then the app will be migrated on the next git push.

The problem is that we are not using buildpacks but instead build our own slug which we publish through the heroku API.

Is there a way to trigger the migration without pushing to the heroku git repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the stack using the build API you need to send the stack as part of the Slug create post call.

e.g

```
local response=`curl -X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3' \
-d { \
  "process_types": { \
    "web": "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djetty.port=$PORT -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --config jetty.xml target/xxxx.war" \
  }, \
  "stack": "cedar-14" \
} \
-n https://api.heroku.com/apps/EXAMPLE_APP/slugs`
```

This will change your stack!

NOTE: You need to include the correct JVM when creating the slug